# how to have a good print with printer dot matrix

Tags: java, printing

i am trying to using pentaho report..

but i dont know why when i print it with printer dot matrix lx-300, the result always bad.

[image]

but when i tried to print it other printer ...the result always good..

i think pentaho report is not support for printer dot matrix..

thats why i want to know..what kind printer are support to pentaho report (some printer like dot matrix )

Comment: It has nothing to do with the dot matrix printing method.  You're using a crappy printer with extremely low resolution.  You could check to see whether it has a higher resolution mode.

Comment: really? but my customers are using printer EPSON dotmatrix , can i know minimun printer can be use?

Comment: "but my customers are using printer EPSON dotmatrix" - is that the same as yours??? EPSON has manufactured a lot of matrix printers with different quality. "minimun printer can be use" - what you're looking for a quality, which is very subjective, how we could know what is good enough for you? However buying any new printer will likely print text in good quality.

Comment: It's hard to tell the scale, but that looks like well under 100 dpi, which is very crude.  Fine mode on a fax is 200 dpi, which is still crude looking.  Laser printers sometimes have a "draft" mode at 300 dpi, and use 600 dpi for good looking text output.  To get reasonable looking resolutions on a dot matrix (240 dpi to 360 dpi) requires a method where a high-res printhead prints at its maximum resolution, then the paper is moved a tiny amount and the printhead does the next pass.  It is a very slow process.  Your output looks like maybe dot matrix draft mode for maximum print speed.

Comment: oh i see.. then i must use printer where more than 369dpi?

Comment: @akiong, if you "address" a comment with @, the person will get an alert to the post.  Otherwise, nobody will be aware of it.  You aren't likely to find a dot matrix printer that can do better than about 360 dpi.  That's about the upper limit on a hi-res dot matrix using a very slow, high quality mode.  And those printers aren't usually designed for commercial workloads.  A workhorse printer will probably have lower resolution (fewer, bigger pins in the printhead).  Look for one that can do 180 or 240 dpi in a single pass that meets your speed requirements.  It will at least be an improvement.

Comment: @fixer1234 okay..thank you..i get it now

Comment: @fixer1234 my fault just on the font, i just need to change my font, then i will have a good printing.

Answer (score 0):

you should change your fonts to another font styles which are highly recommended by the printer. 
otherwise you can change the printer to lq-300
lx  models - printer head has 9 pins. faster, but low quality.
lq  models - printer head has 24 pins. slow, but good quality.